# webview's loaddata() not displaying the image when supply html code as String?

Tags: android, html, webview

```
Webview wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
``String str="<html>
            <body>
            <img src='file:///android_asset/nag.png' height='300' width='200'/>
            </body>
            </html>";
wv.loadData(str,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Load webview with BaseURL given code in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Try using this code

```
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", str, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

Instead of

```
wv.loadData(str,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Six years ago but still works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: "file:///android_asset/" never knew this will be required for loading the URL from string